# How to make graphics disappear off the screen in java?

Tags: java, graphics

I am working on a game similar to bricks, and I want something to disappear off the screen when it is hit. I have gotten my collision detection done, here is the code:

```
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(x,y, 100,25);
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(120,15, 90,40);
        Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(10,15, 90,40);
        Rectangle r4 = new Rectangle(230, 15, 90, 40);
        Rectangle r5 = new Rectangle(xb, yb, 30,29);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(r1.x, r1.y, r1.width, r1.height);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(r2.x, r2.y, r2.width, r2.height);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(r3.x, r3.y, r3.width, r3.height);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(r5.x, r5.y, r5.width, r5.height);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(r4.x, r4.y, r4.width, r4.height);
        if (r5.intersects(r1))
        {
            velxb = -velxb;
            velyb = -velyb; 
        }
        if (r5.intersects(r2))
        {
            g.drawString("Hello", 10, 10);
        }
        if (r5.intersects(r3))
        {
            g.drawString("Hello", 10, 10);
        }
        if (r5.intersects(r4))
        {
            g.drawString("Hello", 10, 10);
        }
```

As you can see I have made a couple of rectangle and have done the collision detection. However, when `r5` intersects with `r2` or `r3` or `r4`, I want it to disappear.

Comment: What framework?  Swing? AWT? JavaFX? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Painting is a destructive process.  Each time your `paintXxx` method is called, you are expected to rebuild the out put, that is, clear the existing `Graphics` context and repaint everything you want.

You engine should make all the decisions about what effects should occur against the model and the UI should render the model...doing collision detection in your paint process really isn't recommended